# How can I retrieve the current workbook path in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How can I retrieve the current directory path for an active workbook in Excel?

For example: Say I want to reference a worksheet located in the same directory as my currently active workbook. My current workbook is located at `C:\My Documents\Sample.xls`.

In this scenario, I would want an Excel formula to return `C:\My Documents\`.

Answer (score 4):

> **To get workbook location** (C:\My Documents\)
>
> ```
> =LEFT(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1))-1)
> ```
>
> **Note:** If you have never saved active workbook before, the first two formulas will return #VALUE! errors, while the formula
>   =CELL("filename",A1) will return blank.

- Source: [Extend Office - How To Get The Active Workbook Location/Path In Excel?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3188-excel-get-workbook-location.html)

Answer (score 3):

The least complex way to do this is by using `INFO("Directory")` as shown below:

## [image: Example using the INFO function]

Comment: `=INFO("DIRECTORY")` gives the current working directory, not the location of the current file.

Comment: Ah good point. Often these are the same thing but it looks like sometimes it isn't.